# C# How to play multiple sounds/songs with the same sound player

Tags: c#

Hello im trying to make a music playlist and so far i made a checkboxlist with the titles of the songs and if you check for example the first one and you hit the play button the song will play by a sound player. I want all my songs in this list to play by the same sound player. Can i do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details, such as the code you wrote, issues you're running into, etc. As written, it's not clear what is working, what isn't, and what issue you're running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i do that?

Yes, you definitely can. It's implementable in C#. You just call a function like

```
player.stopPlaying();
```

and then

```
player.startPlaying(new_song);
```

Comment: okay thank you, i fixed that. Do you know if there is a pause property or something that i can use? for example i have a song playing with a button clicked and i have another button which is for pausing the song but if i click the play button again i want to play the song from the point i paused it. Do you have any idea how can i do that?

Comment: Just name the player you are using. What is the library name? And then enter its name in Google search and look for some docs with the description of all the commands.